# Access Array In PHP Multidimention master to detail elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have array Multidimention, that i designed to master to detail information.

This array Looked like this :

```
Array
(
[BSIU2473289] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID_BARANG] => 13649
                [THICK] => 0.70
                [SIZE] => 0.70MM X 151.8MM    
                [COIL_NO] => 02NKXTL16064945/48            
                [NET] => 2772
                [GROSS] => 2808
                [CONTRACT_NO] => N512C56LJ02         
                [LOCATION] => 
                [NO_URUT] =>   5785
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID_BARANG] => 13657
                [THICK] => 0.70
                [SIZE] => 0.70MM X 151.8MM    
                [COIL_NO] => 02NKXTL16065029/36            
                [NET] => 3512
                [GROSS] => 3552
                [CONTRACT_NO] => N512C56LJ02         
                [LOCATION] => 
                [NO_URUT] =>   5784
            )

        )
  )
```

I want to create a report based this array :

**REPORT DUMMY**

```
No : BSIU2473289

CONTAINS :  

[ID_BARANG] => 13649
[THICK] => 0.70
[SIZE] => 0.70MM X 151.8MM    
[COIL_NO] => 02NKXTL16064945/48            
[NET] => 2772
[GROSS] => 2808
[CONTRACT_NO] => N512C56LJ02         
[LOCATION] => 
[NO_URUT] =>   5785
[CONTAINER] => BSIU2473289
```

So on, so on.

How can I make the looping like this ?

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header" >
      <!--<img src="D:\xampp\htdocs\develop_tsurumaru\assets\admin\img\logo_tli_web.png">-->
      <!-- <img src="./assets/admin/img/logo_tli_web.jpg"> -->
    </div>

    <div class="document-title"  style='margin-top : 120px;'>
      <hr>
      <h1>Check List<br>Check Sheet for PT. Hanwa Indonesia </h1>
    </div>



    <div class="master" style="width: 40%; display: inline-block">
      <table class="table" style="border: none;">

        <tr style="border:none">
          <td style="height:20px; border: none; text-align: left; width: 30%;">Container No</td>
          <td style="border: none; width:5%;">: </td>
          <td style="border: none; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo BSIU243289 ?></td>
        </tr>



      </table>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top : -100px" >
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">NO</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="width: 20%">SIZE</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="width: 18%">CODE OF COIL</th>
            <th rowspan="2">WGHT (NET)</th>
            <th rowspan="2">WGHT (GROSS)</th>
            <th rowspan="2"style="width: 8%">CONTRACT NO</th>
            <th rowspan="2">LOCATION</th>
            <th colspan="3">DENT</th>
            <th rowspan="2">WET</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="font-size: smaller">NO<br>DMG</th>
            <th rowspan="2">OTH</th>
            <th rowspan="2">NO URUT</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th style="width: 3%">In</th>
            <th style="width: 3%">Out</th>
            <th style="width: 3%">End</th>
          </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <?php
          $i = 1;
          $total_net = 0;
          $total_gross = 0;
          ?>

          <?php foreach ($row as $key => $value) : ?>
            <?php
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$i</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['SIZE'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['COIL_NO'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['NET'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['GROSS'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['CONTRACT_NO'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['LOCATION'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['NO_URUT'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $total_net += $value['NET'];
            $total_gross = $value['GROSS'];
            $i++;
            ?>
          <?php endforeach;  ?>

          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Total :</td>
            <td><?= $total_net ?></td>
            <td><?= $total_gross ?></td>
            <td colspan="9"></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>


        </tbody>

      </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: WHat you have tried??

Comment: What about other one? your expected outcome have only one array value which is `0` index values only

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: I have posted code . Please correct your mistake in code

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code .

```
<?php

$arr = Array
(
'BSIU2473289' => Array
    (
        0 => Array
            (
                'ID_BARANG' => '13649',
                'THICK' => '44',
                'SIZE' => '0.70MM X 151.8MM'   , 
                'COIL_NO' => '02NKXTL16064945/48' ,           
                'NET' => '2772',
                'GROSS' => '2808',
                'CONTRACT_NO' => 'N512C56LJ02'      ,   
                'LOCATION' => '',
                'NO_URUT'=>   '5785'
            ),

        1 => Array
            (
                'ID_BARANG'=> '13657',
                'THICK' => '0.70',
                'SIZE'=> '0.70MM X 151.8MM' ,   
                'COIL_NO' => '02NKXTL16065029/36' ,           
                'NET' => '3512',
                'GROSS' => '3552',
                'CONTRACT_NO' => 'N512C56LJ02'  ,       
                'LOCATION' =>'' ,
                'NO_URUT' =>   '5784'
            )

        ),
  );



$first_key =  key($arr);
foreach ($arr[$first_key] as $key => $value) {

    $chunk = $arr[$first_key][$key];
    foreach ($chunk as $key1 => $value) {
        echo  $arr[$first_key][$key][$key1]."<br>";
    }
}


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed end of foreach statement

```
    <?php $a = array(
    "BSIU2473289" => array(
        "0" => array
            (
                "ID_BARANG" => 13649,
                "THICK" => 0.70,
                "SIZE" => "0.70MM X 151.8MM",
                "COIL_NO" => "02NKXTL16064945/48" ,           
                "NET" => 2772,
                "GROSS" => 2808,
                "CONTRACT_NO" => "N512C56LJ02",      
                "LOCATION" => "",
                "NO_URUT" =>   5785,
            ),

        "1" => array
            (
                "ID_BARANG" => 13657,
                "THICK" => 0.70,
                "SIZE" => "0.70MM X 151.8MM",
                "COIL_NO" => "02NKXTL16065029/36",          
                "NET" => 3512,
                "GROSS" => 3552,
                "CONTRACT_NO" => "N512C56LJ02",
                "LOCATION" => "",
                "NO_URUT" =>   5784
            ),
        )
  );

?>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header" >
      <!--<img src="D:\xampp\htdocs\develop_tsurumaru\assets\admin\img\logo_tli_web.png">-->
      <!-- <img src="./assets/admin/img/logo_tli_web.jpg"> -->
    </div>

    <div class="document-title"  style='margin-top : 120px;'>
      <hr>
      <h1>Check List<br>Check Sheet for PT. Hanwa Indonesia </h1>
    </div>



    <div class="master" style="width: 40%; display: inline-block">
        <table class="table" style="border: none;">
            <tr style="border:none">
              <td style="height:20px; border: none; text-align: left; width: 30%;">Container No</td>
              <td style="border: none; width:5%;">: </td>
              <td style="border: none; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo BSIU243289 ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top : -100px" >
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">NO</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="width: 20%">SIZE</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="width: 18%">CODE OF COIL</th>
            <th rowspan="2">WGHT (NET)</th>
            <th rowspan="2">WGHT (GROSS)</th>
            <th rowspan="2"style="width: 8%">CONTRACT NO</th>
            <th rowspan="2">LOCATION</th>
            <th colspan="3">DENT</th>
            <th rowspan="2">WET</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="font-size: smaller">NO<br>DMG</th>
            <th rowspan="2">OTH</th>
            <th rowspan="2">NO URUT</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th style="width: 3%">In</th>
            <th style="width: 3%">Out</th>
            <th style="width: 3%">End</th>
          </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <?php
          $i = 1;
          $total_net = 0;
          $total_gross = 0;
          ?>

        <?php foreach ($a as $row): ?>
        <?php foreach ($row as $key => $value) : ?>
            <?php
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$i</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['SIZE'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['COIL_NO'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". (int)$value['NET'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". (int)$value['GROSS'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['CONTRACT_NO'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['LOCATION'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td>". $value['NO_URUT'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $total_net += $value['NET'];
            $total_gross = $value['GROSS'];
            $i++;
            ?>
          <?php endforeach;
          endforeach;  ?>

          <tr>
            <td >Total :</td>
            <td><?php echo $total_net;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $total_gross ?></td>
            <!-- <td colspan="9"></td> -->
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of your `foreach` loops was never closed and some of your html tags were in the wrong place.
If you want a separate table for each of the top level elements, e.g. one table for BSIU2473289 and on table for BSIU24712345, this is how to do it. 
Please check the sample output in the demo.

```
<?php 
    $result=array ( 'BSIU2473289'=>array ( 0 => array ( 'ID_BARANG' => '13649', 'THICK' => '0.70', 'SIZE' => '0.70MM X 151.8MM', 'COIL_NO' => '02NKXTL16064945/48', 'NET' => '2772', 'GROSS' => '2808', 'CONTRACT_NO' => 'N512C56LJ02', 'LOCATION' => '', 'NO_URUT' => ' 5785', ), 1 => array
    ( 'ID_BARANG' => '13657', 'THICK' => '0.70', 'SIZE' => '0.70MM X 151.8MM', 'COIL_NO' => '02NKXTL16065029/36', 'NET' => '3512', 'GROSS' => '3552', 'CONTRACT_NO' => 'N512C56LJ02', 'LOCATION' => '', 'NO_URUT' => ' 5784', ), ),  'BSIU24712345'=>array ( 0 => array ( 'ID_BARANG' => '13649', 'THICK' => '0.70', 'SIZE' => '0.70MM X 151.8MM', 'COIL_NO' => '02NKXTL16064945/48', 'NET' => '2772', 'GROSS' => '2808', 'CONTRACT_NO' => 'N512C56LJ02', 'LOCATION' => '', 'NO_URUT' => ' 5785', ), 1 => array
    ( 'ID_BARANG' => '13657', 'THICK' => '0.70', 'SIZE' => '0.70MM X 151.8MM', 'COIL_NO' => '02NKXTL16065029/36', 'NET' => '3512', 'GROSS' => '3552', 'CONTRACT_NO' => 'N512C56LJ02', 'LOCATION' => '', 'NO_URUT' => ' 5784', ), ),); 
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header" >
      <!--<img src="D:\xampp\htdocs\develop_tsurumaru\assets\admin\img\logo_tli_web.png">-->
      <!-- <img src="./assets/admin/img/logo_tli_web.jpg"> -->
    </div>

    <div class="document-title"  style='margin-top : 120px;'>
      <hr>
      <h1>Check List<br>Check Sheet for PT. Hanwa Indonesia </h1>
    </div>
    <?php 
        foreach($result as $heading=>$row){ 
    ?>
    <div class="master" style="width: 40%; display: inline-block">
      <table class="table" style="border: none;">
        <tr style="border:none">
          <td style="height:20px; border: none; text-align: left; width: 30%;">Container No</td>
          <td style="border: none; width:5%;">: </td>
          <td style="border: none; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $heading ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

            <div style="padding-top : -100px">
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">NO</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 20%">SIZE</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 18%">CODE OF COIL</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WGHT (NET)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WGHT (GROSS)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 8%">CONTRACT NO</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">LOCATION</th>
                    <th colspan="3">DENT</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WET</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="font-size:smaller">NO<br>DMG</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">OTH</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">NO URUT</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3%">In</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%">Out</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%">End</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <?php
                $i=1 ; 
                $total_net=0 ; 
                $total_gross=0 ; 
                   foreach ($row as $item){ 
                    echo "<tr>"; 
                    echo "<td>$i</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>". $item['SIZE'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>". $item['COIL_NO'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>". $item['NET'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>". $item['GROSS'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>". $item['CONTRACT_NO'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>". $item['LOCATION'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td></td>"; 
                    echo "<td></td>"; 
                    echo "<td></td>"; 
                    echo "<td></td>"; 
                    echo "<td></td>"; 
                    echo "<td></td>"; 
                    echo "<td>". $item['NO_URUT'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "</tr>"; 

                    $total_net += $item['NET']; 
                    $total_gross = $item['GROSS']; 
                    $i++; 
                    } 
                ?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total :</td>
        <td><?= $total_net ?></td>
        <td><?= $total_gross ?></td>
        <td colspan="9"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  <?php   
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Sample Output

```css
table {
  color: #333;
  /* Lighten up font color */
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  /* Nicer font */
  width: 640px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  height: 30px;
}
/* Make cells a bit taller */

th {
  background: #F3F3F3;
  /* Light grey background */
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Make sure they're bold */
}
td {
  background: #FAFAFA;
  /* Lighter grey background */
  text-align: center;
  /* Center our text */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header" >
      <!--<img src="D:\xampp\htdocs\develop_tsurumaru\assets\admin\img\logo_tli_web.png">-->
      <!-- <img src="./assets/admin/img/logo_tli_web.jpg"> -->
    </div>

    <div class="document-title"  style='margin-top : 120px;'>
      <hr>
      <h1>Check List<br>Check Sheet for PT. Hanwa Indonesia </h1>
    </div>
        <div class="master" style="width: 40%; display: inline-block">
      <table class="table" style="border: none;">
        <tr style="border:none">
          <td style="height:20px; border: none; text-align: left; width: 30%;">Container No</td>
          <td style="border: none; width:5%;">: </td>
          <td style="border: none; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">BSIU2473289</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

            <div style="padding-top : -100px">
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">NO</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 20%">SIZE</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 18%">CODE OF COIL</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WGHT (NET)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WGHT (GROSS)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 8%">CONTRACT NO</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">LOCATION</th>
                    <th colspan="3">DENT</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WET</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="font-size:smaller">NO<br>DMG</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">OTH</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">NO URUT</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3%">In</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%">Out</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%">End</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>0.70MM X 151.8MM</td><td>02NKXTL16064945/48</td><td>2772</td><td>2808</td><td>N512C56LJ02</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td> 5785</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>0.70MM X 151.8MM</td><td>02NKXTL16065029/36</td><td>3512</td><td>3552</td><td>N512C56LJ02</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td> 5784</td></tr>        <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total :</td>
        <td>6284</td>
        <td>3552</td>
        <td colspan="9"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
   </div>
      <div class="master" style="width: 40%; display: inline-block">
      <table class="table" style="border: none;">
        <tr style="border:none">
          <td style="height:20px; border: none; text-align: left; width: 30%;">Container No</td>
          <td style="border: none; width:5%;">: </td>
          <td style="border: none; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">BSIU24712345</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

            <div style="padding-top : -100px">
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">NO</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 20%">SIZE</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 18%">CODE OF COIL</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WGHT (NET)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WGHT (GROSS)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 8%">CONTRACT NO</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">LOCATION</th>
                    <th colspan="3">DENT</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">WET</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" style="font-size:smaller">NO<br>DMG</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">OTH</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">NO URUT</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3%">In</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%">Out</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%">End</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>0.70MM X 151.8MM</td><td>02NKXTL16064945/48</td><td>2772</td><td>2808</td><td>N512C56LJ02</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td> 5785</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>0.70MM X 151.8MM</td><td>02NKXTL16065029/36</td><td>3512</td><td>3552</td><td>N512C56LJ02</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td> 5784</td></tr>        <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total :</td>
        <td>6284</td>
        <td>3552</td>
        <td colspan="9"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```